# Android print text on printer

Tags: android, network-printers

I am developing a restaurant app which print receipts after customer purchases foods. I have added a config screen in app which the manager uses to configure printers. A manager can print a test page to test whether he has entered right ip and port. Here is my code which prints test page:

```
private class PrintTask extends AsyncTask<Printer, Boolean, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Printer... params) {

        try {
            publishProgress(true);
            Socket sock = new Socket(params[0].getIp(), Integer.parseInt(params[0].getPort()));

            PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            oStream.printf("--------------------------------\r\n");
            oStream.printf("***        TEST PRINT       ***\r\n");
            oStream.printf("You have configured your \n\r");
            oStream.printf(params[0].getName());
            oStream.printf("\r\nprinter successfully\n\r");
            oStream.printf("|           Thanks             |\r\n");
            oStream.printf("--------------------------------\r\n");
            oStream.close();
            sock.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(false);
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if(!values[0]) {
            waitView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            waitView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is if I print on a network printer (a stand alone printer without attaching to any PC) it prints text properly. Here I am using the ip and default port 9100. But when I print to a shared printer attached to a PC, it fails to print. Any idea, where I am doing wrong...???

Comment: can you please specify what printer did you use? I have tried this code on a Brother HL-2135W and it fails to output anything.

Comment: It was some HP LaserJet printer. Did you add the access internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: I did. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: The problem is the app connects to the printer because the printer's led flashes showing some transfer of data, but it just won't print. Not even rubbish text, not even an empty page :(

Comment: Can you verify that the methods oStream.close();  sock.close(); are being called? Because what I guess is, printer prints when sockets closes.

Comment: i use logcat and it does print closing the socket and all, but the printer still does not print :(

Comment: It must print if everything is going proper.
 Here is Brother printer's play store app. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brother.mfc.brprint
Decompile the apk and try to find out how does they print?

Comment: @KhawarRaza Can you please answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094911/how-to-give-print-command-to-printer-from-android-app

Answer (score 0):

From what your describe it looks like that standalone printer is running some kind of "text printing service" on your given port. So looks like everything you send to this port will be printed as text.

Whereas when you have "Shared" printer on your Windows machine, it's implemented using Windows Printer service or smth like that. It's not just simple socket/port anymore where you can write ASCII text.

Comment: I think so. Any idea how to send print on such a shared printer?

Comment: Looks like the only proper way to print from Android is to use Cloud Print service.

You will need to make your printer availble throught Google Cloud Print [link]http://www.howtogeek.com/165778/everything-you-need-to-know-about-printing-from-your-android-phone-or-tablet/ (it will become attached to your google account) and later you can use [Google  Print Cloud API]https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/ to print.

Comment: Or other simplier option would be just write a simple "server" program which will be running on windows computer (the one with the shared printer) and will be listening for text commands and sending them to printer accordingly. This way your code on android devices stays the same, and only windows side gets more sophisticated.

Comment: Yeah, actually my server has similar set of functionality as my android app and they are doing the same using some dot net thing but the client wants to print locally instead of first sending request to server and then back to local printer.

Comment: @DimitryK Can you please answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094911/how-to-give-print-command-to-printer-from-android-app