# Connect Printer to android device via wi - fi router

Tags: android, android-print-framework

My printer and android device is connected to a Wi-Fi router. I need to print a text from my application which should be sent via the router to the printer.

How to establish the connection?

Note : i need not want to connect the printer directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just searched for lot of links but there is no luck, what i did is go to printer settings change the port to TCP/IP and assign RAW port. By default you will get 9100, use this port number in the code with respective IP address of the printer. You will get the fruit.

For code refer 
[Code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146159/android-print-text-on-printer)

Comment: hello. could you describe me the solution you found, please ? model of router/wifi adapter, settings made to it. thanks.